# start-stop-daemon: option '--exec' requires an argument

Tags: init.d

I do not understand this error: start-stop-daemon: option `--exec` requires an argument

I am very new to the `init.d` world and have only just got my script going using service calls, I just want to get this script working, it starts on boot but failed because of this error any help? (any suggestions or rewrites are welcome even if not related to my issue)

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# shell script to ...

#set the full path to the programs we need to use
NTOP=/opt/bash_scripts/start-up-superscript &
KILLALL=/usr/bin/killall

case "$1" in
        start)

                   echo "Starting SDD Install..."
                start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --exec $NTOP
                ;;
        stop)
                #kill ntop
                echo "Stopping SSD..."
                $KILLALL ntop           
                ;;
        restart)
                $0 stop
                $0 start
                ;;
        status)
                ;;
        *)
                echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
                ;;
esac
```

Comment: I think that the form:

   `NTOP=/opt/bash_scripts/start-up-superscript & `
must be:

    `NTOP=/opt/bash_scripts/start-up-superscript`

Comment: Yea i changed that and added the & here: start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --exec $NTOP & ... this now works fine... BUT I cannot kill the process :/ ?? any ideas why it is not killing the process?

Comment: try $KILLALL $NTOP

Comment: @LilloX root@linaro-alip:~# service start-up-ssd stop
Stopping SSD...
/opt/bash_scripts/start-up-ssd: no process found

I can kill it if I type /bin/bash ... but this would obviously kill all bash scripts... :/ dunno what to do (I just tried your suggestion but the out put of NTOP is /bin/bash /opt/bash_scripts/start-up-ssd)

Comment: But $NTOP has not the value /opt/bash_scripts/start-up-superscript ? So you want to kill a process run by start-up-superscript? if you do a start and then do a `ps -ef` did you find "/opt/bash_scripts/start-up-superscript"?

Comment: @LilloX root      1629     1  1 11:54 ttymxc1  00:00:00 /bin/bash /opt/bash_scripts/star....

Comment: Ok, I will make an answer with some modifications to your script.

Answer (score 1):

I quote here the changes in the comments and shared editing for the kill process.
As for the start you need to remove the **&** from the definition of the name of the service to start.

In order to identify the process to stop, since in the launch it is added the interpreter, it is convenient to use a PID. So your script may be modify as:

```
#!/bin/bash
# shell script to ...
set -e

#set the full path to the programs we need to use
NTOP=/opt/bash_scripts/start-up-superscript
PIDFILE=/var/run/start-up-superscript.pid
case "$1" in
        start)
            echo "Starting SDD Install..."
            start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo --exec $NTOP --pidfile $PIDFILE -m
            ;;
        stop)
            #kill ntop
            echo "Stopping SSD..."
            start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE
            ;;
        restart)
            $0 stop
            $0 start
            ;;
        status)
            ;;
        *)
                echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
                ;;
esac
```

In this way the whole process start and stop should work as you want.